# How do I get rid of ugly creases from loop cuts?

Tags: mesh, edges, geometry

So I'm creating a spider in Blender and after adding a material to my mesh, I noticed in render mode that there was an ugly crease torwards the head (highlighted in yellow in edit mode). I did not mark the area as a seam before UV unwrapping it. I think it's the edge loop that is causing it.

Is there a way to get rid of this ugly crease???

Here is a screenshot of my mesh and a copy of my [Blender file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah2aL3r7RO3TwnDHQohc2mwrtEDM).

[image]

Comment: maybe share this part of your object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I linked it under "Blender file."

Comment: first of all you don't need to push the subsurf subdivision up to 4 or 5... 2 should be enough most of the case, then press the Smoot Shading on the Tools panel (panel on the left of the 3D view). About your problem: It's hard to know because you didn't pack the images that are used in the nodes, but it's probably the reason, you gave your object a Normal map that influences its appearance. Maybe share a new file with the images packed this time?